# Link Sharepoint List entries to Sharepoint Library

Tags: list

I have an existing Sharepoint List but I would like to be able to send the entries and attachments to individuals and collect their comments.  I can collect comments via a workflow associated with a library.  Is there a way to automatically export Sharepoint List entries into a Sharepoint library?  Or create a workflow from a list?

Comment: You mean sort of like an approval review?

Comment: Is this for SharePoint online ? Can you use Microsoft Flow ?